# preg_replace url with md5 string

Tags: php, preg-replace, md5

I'm trying to remove a substring from a string. String is a HTML document and substring is as followed:

```
t.php?t=71f51692772c336bd9bb26d93c985eb5 <= Always a MD5 hash.
```

The `t.php?t=MD5Hash` should be replaced by `1.gif`.

I've tried with the following example. However that isn't working:

```
$FileHTML = preg_replace("t.php?t=/^[0-9a-f]{32}$/i", "1.gif", $FileHTML);
```

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Your delimiter is in the wrong place. `/t.php?t=[0-9a-f]{32}$/i` is correct usage of it

Comment: @AlmaDo Except `^` is still wrong.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol right, I just missed it. Fixed, thanks (leaved that without `^` at all since, I believe, it shouldn't be there at all)

Answer (score 3):

An often repeated phrase: Yer doin' it wrong!

```
$FileHTML = preg_replace("/\Qt.php?t=\E[0-9a-f]{32}/i","1.gif",$FileHTML);
```

Explanation:

- `\Q`: Literally match...

  - `t.php?t=`
- `\E`: Literal match ends here
- `[0-9a-f]{32}`: match 32 hexits

Note: Don't use `^` and `$` for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this

```
$FileHTML = preg_replace("/[t.php?t=]+[0-9a-f]{32}/i","1.gif",$FileHTML);
```